# Cannot mock the query string in HttpRequestBase for unit test

Tags: c#, http, .net-core, nsubstitute

I have the following code that I need to unit test:

```
public ActionResult VerifyVoucherCode()
        {
            var model = new VerifyVoucherModel();

            model.Voucher = Request.GetFirstQueryValue("token", "voucher");
```

The second line here is where my test fails. The code for this method is:

```
        public static string GetFirstQueryValue(this HttpRequestBase request, params string[] keys)
        {
            return request.QueryString.GetFirstValue(keys);
        }
```

My attempt to unit test this part of the method so far is:

```
            var httpContext = CreateHttpContext();
            var httpRequestBase = new HttpRequestWrapper(httpContext.Request);
            var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();

            var controller = CreateMvcController<SignUpController>();
            MockActivationCodeHelper(validationResult, controller);
```

For reference, the CreateHttpContext method is:

```
        private HttpContext CreateHttpContext()
        {
            var httpContext = new HttpContext(
                new HttpRequest("", "http://tempuri.org", "token=123"),
                new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())
            );

            return httpContext;
        }
```

It fails here `return request.QueryString.GetFirstValue(keys);` with a System Not Implemented exception for Query String. Any pointers here please?

Comment: Not seeing how the request and the controller are related. Where is the request assigned to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at flurl, while it may require some refactoring to your code, using it allows to construct http requests in a very handy and fluent way. Moreover, it makes testing your business logic that depends on calling external HTTP services extremely easy (event for edge cases)
The library has good documentation and his author is very responsive on stackoverflow.

Check out: https://flurl.dev/